# Looking for trouble: the κ letter, the combining ⃗, ucharclasses and xparse... (error with κ⃗ but not with k⃗)

Tags: xetex, xparse

Now I'm seriously puzzled. Here's the MWE (using xelatex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\li}{v}{\texttt{#1}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
  \setTransitionsFor{GreekAndCoptic}{\begingroup\fontspec[Scale=.85]{DejaVu Sans}}{\endgroup}
  \setTransitionsFor{CombiningDiacriticalMarksforSymbols}{\begingroup\fontspec{DejaVu Sans}}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
  \li+κ⃗+
\end{document}
```

I believe the title says it all. I'm getting:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> \egroup 

l.16   \li+κ⃗+

?
```

Things work fine if I write either `κ⃗`, i.e. without the call to  `\li`, or if I write `\li+k⃗+`, i.e. without the greek κ but with a roman k instead.

It's not that it's blocking me or anything (I switched to k instead of κ for my variable), but I'm just very, very curious as to why this is happening!

Comment: Do you have any problems if you change the definition of `\li` to not use verbose arguments?

Comment: Nothing really to do with `xparse`: if you try your setup with just `κ⃗` in the input stream you'll see there is a warning in the log that a group has not been closed.

Comment: Correct. I just hadn't noticed the error until I wrapped the thing in xparse. That still leaves open the question of why the \begingroup and \endgroup commands are not well-parenthesized.